# Is listening to Brainwave Entrainment‎ or subliminal message audio halal?

Tags: halal-haram, software, medical

As the title says, I want to determine if Brainwave Entrainment is halaal or haraam?

Brainwave Entrainment in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainwave_entrainment):

> Brainwave Entrainment is any practice that aims to cause brainwave
>   frequencies to fall into step with a periodic stimulus having a
>   frequency corresponding to the intended brain-state (for example, to
>   induce sleep), usually attempted with the use of specialized software.
>   It purportedly depends upon a "frequency following" response on the
>   assumption that the human brain has a tendency to change its dominant
>   EEG frequency towards the frequency of a dominant external
>   stimulus.[citation needed] Such a stimulus is often aural, as in the
>   case of binaural or monaural beats and isochronic tones, or else
>   visual, as with a dreamachine, a combination of the two with a mind
>   machine, or even electromagnetic radiation.

And about [subliminal messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli):

> Kaser, V.A. "The Effects of an Auditory Subliminal Perception Message
>   Upon the Production of Images and Dreams". Journal of Nervous and
>   Mental Disease (1986). Subjects listened to an audio subliminal
>   message. The message was mixed with a regular music recording. Another
>   group of subjects simply listened to the regular music recording
>   without the subliminals. Both groups were asked to create a pre-test
>   drawing before and immediately after the music was played as well as a
>   drawing of any dreams they had the previous night. When the drawings
>   were examined, the effects of the subliminal message could be seen.
>   The drawings of the people who listened to the music with subliminal
>   hidden content contained images relating to the suggestions they were
>   listening to, whereas no correlation could be found with the control
>   group. Kaser concluded that "the unconscious/subconscious mind is able
>   to perceive a recorded verbal message that cannot be consciously
>   heard", proving the existence of subliminal perception

The explanation behind subliminal message is giving suggestion to penetrate to subconscious and it repeated many times. The purpose form me is for self help. If after listen the brainwave or subliminal message audio and giving result, I believe this is from Allah.

Answer (score 1):

## Brainwave Entrainment

This is a vast science, mostly used in medical applications. Most people will associate the word Entertainment with music, when it [actually](http://www.transparentcorp.com/products/np/entrainment.php) is:

> Entrainment is a principle of physics. It is defined as the synchronization of two or more rhythmic cycles. The principles of entrainment appear in chemistry, neurology, biology, pharmacology, medicine, astronomy and more.

As such I do not see a reason why this would be Haram. However, this opinion does come from someone who does not think that Music is haram in Islam.

## Subliminal Stimuli

A small note that this only works on People with certain [neurological disorders](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-subliminal-stimuli.htm#). It won't work on normal healthy people.

This I won't call a science since there isn't really any scientific evidence that any research was done. There are a few instances where a research was claimed but never published.

Most of the research done is when people hear something, they tend to select that. That isn't brain science, it is common sense. If I hear the word snickers a few times and someone offers me snickers or mars, I would choose snickers. This isn't subliminal or anything but rather what sticks to your mind.

There are a few [requirements](http://www.nickkolenda.com/subliminal-messages/) for this to work:

- Limitation #1: People Must Already Have a Need. Drink campaigns will only work if something is thirsty.
- Limitation #2: Subliminal Messages in Self Help Tapes. Does not work, mostly placebo effect.

In the end, I don't think this is Haram as it is no science, mostly sales techniques that don't even work.

Answer (score -3):

its undoubtedly haram, why? because it include Rythm and its sound is musical in nature. So as in islam all sorts of music and musician instruments are haram, so Brainwave Entrainment is alow haram.

Comment: http://www.islam-qa.com/en/ref/5000

Comment: You should read "Diversion and Arts in Islam" by Sheikh Yusuf Al-Qaradawi (one of the most respected scholars of the current era and certainly considered conservative in other matters).  Available in Arabic and translated into English.  A very good read.

Comment: The Best rule that i know is "Prevention is better than cure", and a hadith too which states that halal and haram are clear, so if there is any doubt in something,then simply leave it. So as there is doubt that something halal or haram, then why not just leave it??? 
Why TAKE RISK at all???
Safest way is to stay away from every type of music (because music is not something which is basic necessity of our live that we cannot live without it.

Comment: There is a rule that says "Nothing can be forbidden except by a [religious] text".  The book I mentioned demonstrates this in greater detail than I can go into here but it does make the point that some of the hadith that are often quoted are daeef (weak) and that others are out of context or misunderstood. It also references other hadith that demonstrate situations in which the Prophet (pbuh) allowed music/singing in his presence. The hadith you quote is a good rule to use but it must be within reason. If you are not careful, everything will become haram because we want to "stay safe".

Comment: Indeed, that is why i did not said that it is Forbidden :) , i just said to Avoid it (without making it Haram).
When we will avoid it,then there wont be any risk at all of doing any sin ever... 
And everything cannot be made haram or avoided... because during my study of islam since last 6 years, there re just countable (less than 10 issues) which were to be avoided, otherwise everything is clear according to Quran and Sunnah, that its mubah,haram, halal, or else...

Comment: With all due respect, you said in your answer that "in islam all sorts of music and musician instruments are haram" so you did say it's forbidden. The general rule is that everything is halal (permissable) except that which is explicitly stated to be haram (forbidden). The book I mentioned states that music does not fall into this category. As for the reasoning getting out of control, I have seen people avoid using TV altogether for wanting to "stay safe" and this same reasoning could stop people from using phones, computers and the internet. Again, one must be careful with this reasoning.

Comment: according to scholars, it is.. so to be on safest side, i will go with ruling of those scholars, who say that it is haram. I cannot just based the Whole rulings on just one scholar's opinion, that is why i go with getting more and more fawtas, and i came to know that more than 80% scholar (that i know of, and many themselves say that its Ijma of scholars), that music is haram by all means, keeping very little exceptions of duff etc.
And indeed, TV shouldnt be used, because more than 99% channles on it are broadcasting haram entertainment.

Comment: i myself dont have TV in my home, Alhamdulillah. regarding phones and computers, logically we have CONTROL over what we want to see and what not to (besides case of TV, where you dont have control over what you want to see on specific channel, you just have to see,what they want you to see).
Computer can be used in any possible way, same with smartphones. they can be used as a medium of dawah, spread islam, and much much more..like to do research on islam , to learn islam

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQ_Y11yP63k

Comment: Everything you said, same for TV and even music.  All I ask you to do is to read the book I mentioned and decide for yourself.  It is, of course, completely up to you.  May Allah guide both you and I and the whole ummah to the right path.  In the end, salam my brother :)

Comment: @Farhan Actually, Rhythm has been used to recite Quran as well. So the mentioning of rhythm been haram seems does not stand at this case.

Comment: @Adam: Quran is the biggest exception.

Answer (score -3):

Aleykumselam.

I don't know any direct source about this, but according to my opinion, it is logically haram.

If you don't know what you are doing, it wouldn't cause sin according to Islam. Because of this, children and crazy people (please no offense, I couldn't find the right word) are sinless, innocent whatever they do.

But a sane muslim must learn his/her limits and prohibitions. "I didn't know" is a valid excuse, but "I didn't try to learn" is absolutely not valid. A muslim must research, think and behave according to that.

A muslim's mind always should be clear in order to achieve that. Muslim person should be awake and aware of his/her environment, ie surroundings all the time. This is an important reason of why drugs and alcohol is haram. They give damage to your brain and decrease your capacity to understand and think.   [Al-Maidah: 90](http://quran.com/5)

If you listened some music and by the time you didn't know it has subliminal messages, you can be sure they didn't counted as sin. But after that you had learn it has some hidden messages, if you listen them again, it would be haram.

Also I heard that subliminal messages are based on 2 basic instincts defined by Sigmund Freud. They are violence and sexuality. If this is true, and you keep listen to them knowingly, I think it would be haram.

Comment: Logically, some people also think God's existence can't be proved. Islamic teaching can't be simply interpreted by 'logic'. Thanks.

Comment: Without logic, are you expecting a verse from the Qur'an saying something like "Don't listen to music including subliminal messages, it is haram"?

Comment: Logic explanation should be based on Quranic verses or Hadith. Logic itself, will not stand in Islam.

Comment: Blocking your mind and thought is forbidden according to Quranic verses, no matter caused by alcohol or drugs or something else. How can my answer not based on Quranic verses?

Comment: My apology if the statement was not clear. In addition of what I mentioned above, please, always reference the Quran's verses or hadith that back your thought, or logic conclusions. For instance, even in a world of science, you back your work by reference of others "research" of other people, you not just come out of your result from nowhere out of your mind. Does that clarify the reason for a reference of your answer inshaAllah? Jazaklahir

Comment: Ok, you are right, I searched a little bit and couldn't find the correct verses about my answer. But I am pretty sure that my assumptions or rules such as about mindless people or unclearing mind etc are genuine. If somebody knows the exact verses about these, they can edit my answer with correct references.