# Is listening to Brainwave Binaural forbidden?

Tags: halal-haram, music

Is listening to [Brainwave Binaural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_beats) forbidden or is it okay? I do hear often these just to focus on studies, and I find these work for me.

But I'm worried if these are forbidden according to Islamic law, or not.

Comment: Maybe your answer is here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9452/is-listening-to-brainwave-entrainment-or-subliminal-message-audio-halaal-in-isl?s=2|0.8498

Comment: @Medi1Saif, yeah I read this. Seems like they couldn't confirm it, but according to their answer, it is not forbidden, right?

Comment: Unfortunatley I don't know about this stuff. And as far as I can tell the users who answered and those whom's answers have been deleted showed of different points of view.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.