# Is subliminal affirmation to enhance the mind haram?

Tags: halal-haram, medical

If I'm listening a subliminal affirmation for enhancing intelligence and all the affirmation in it are listed clearly and are not against Islam, will it be harram?

Comment: There's questions about [Brainwave Entrainment‎](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9452/17163), [subliminals in general](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38682/17163), [subliminals in eye color](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/34947/17163) ([duplicate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37282/17163)).

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't be, it doesn't change your beliefs on religion or how you think, if it would be harram then you most likely wouldn't get results and if subliminal affirmations were not allowed then they most likely wouldn't even be a thing, plus the subliminal affirmations don't make you think wrong or anything of the sort, I'm not really sure how to reason it honestly, but I wouldn't say it is harram.